# Filling an arc segment in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the scenario as follows, I am drawing an arc between two points in WPF, I need to fill the arc, but I want to fill the arc sector touching the center, but WPF fills up differently. How do I get the arc filled up the way I want?

```
   PathGeometry pathGeometry = new PathGeometry();
   PathFigure pathFigure = new PathFigure();
   pathFigure.StartPoint = start;
   ArcSegment arc = new ArcSegment(end, new Size(radiusX, radiusY), 0.0, large, d, true);  //large & d corresponds to size & direction
   pathFigure.Segments.Add(arc);
   pathGeometry.Figures.Add(pathFigure);
   SolidColorBrush fill = new SolidColorBrush(color);
   drawingContext.DrawGeometry(fill, pen, pathGeometry);
```

My code produces the output as this :  [image]

whereas my requirement is this one:  [image]

Is there a way of getting this done? TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you just need at add a line segment to go along with your arc segment.

```
   PathGeometry pathGeometry = new PathGeometry();
   PathFigure pathFigure = new PathFigure();
   pathFigure.StartPoint = start;
   ArcSegment arc = new ArcSegment(end, new Size(radiusX, radiusY), 0.0, large, d, true);  //large & d corresponds to size & direction
   pathFigure.Segments.Add(arc);

   //line segment takes the path to the origin
   LineSegment line = new LineSegment(new Point(originX, originY), true);
   pathFigure.Segments.Add(line );

   pathGeometry.Figures.Add(pathFigure);
   SolidColorBrush fill = new SolidColorBrush(color);
   drawingContext.DrawGeometry(fill, pen, pathGeometry);
```

Comment: Just so happen to have spent all yesterday playing with arc drawing!